# fetch data for a date period

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
[
  {
    start_time: "09:00",
    end_date: "2015-12-20",
    end_time: "13:55",
    start_date: "2015-12-15"
  },
  {
    start_time: "06:07",
    end_date: "2015-12-24",
    end_time: "08:09",
    start_date: "2015-12-22"
  },
  {
    start_time: "09:30",
    end_date: "2015-12-01",
    end_time: "18:00",
    start_date: "2015-12-01"
  },
  {
    start_time: "01:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "04:00",
    start_date: null,

  },
  {
    start_time: "05:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "08:00",
    start_date: null,

  }
]
```

I've data like above. I will pass start and end dates it has to result data between the dates and if dates are not there then it has to insert null data(dict with start and end dates as null). Example is listed below for a date period between "2015-12-02", "2015-12-16". It has to result like below.

```
[
  {
    start_time: "01:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "04:00",
    start_date: null,

  },
  {
    start_time: "05:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "08:00",
    start_date: null,

  },

  {
    start_time: "09:00",
    end_date: "2015-12-20",
    end_time: "13:55",
    start_date: "2015-12-15"
  },
  {
    start_time: "01:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "04:00",
    start_date: null,

  },
  {
    start_time: "05:00",
    end_date: null,
    end_time: "08:00",
    start_date: null,

  },
  {
    start_time: "06:07",
    end_date: "2015-12-24",
    end_time: "08:09",
    start_date: "2015-12-22"
  }
]
```

can anybody help me here?

Comment: If the range is from Dec-2 and Dec-16, Why have you mentioned Dec-24 & Dec-22 in result? Do you want the whole range to be inside or just any partial range?

Comment: Apologies. the example is for Dec-2 to Dec-24

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should be able to compare between the strings (where the comparison function is date comparison). So I would first convert it to dates -

```
import time
start = "2015-12-02"
start_date = time.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
end = "2015-12-02"
end_date = time.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now you can you ><= operators and iterate over the list of events you have. For each record convert the start_date and end_date and check if they fill the condition you look for.